# working with mysql query not equal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Good day all,

```
    $query = "SELECT hashtag FROM user_information WHERE email != $email";
```

Does not work.

However, without the where contraints, it works fine

```
$query = "SELECT hashtag FROM user_information";
```

I don't think the $email variable is the issue because even replacing it with something like "daniel@gmail.com" does not work.

I want to evaluate only query where the email is different from that of the email post.

This is because I will insert the email into the database, and obviously if this email already exist we do not want to create a second account.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no errors is unfortunatetly returned, but the data is not stored with this line WHERE email != $email";

Comment: check LPK's answer he is correct

Comment: $query = "SELECT `hashtag` FROM user_information WHERE `email` != $email"; OR $query = "SELECT `hashtag` FROM user_information WHERE `email` <> $email";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put apostrophes around your variable like:

```
$query = "SELECT hashtag FROM user_information WHERE email != '$email'";
```